# SVG donut chart not showing up in emails

Tags: html, svg, geometry, handlebars.js, donut-chart

I have the following donut chart:

```
<div class="donut-chart" style="position: relative;">
 <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
   <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff></circle>
   <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#372583" stroke-width="3"></circle>
   <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#26c1c9" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="{{{allocatedPerNorm}}} {{{unallocatedPerNorm}}}" stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
 </svg>

 <div style="position: absolute; left: 45%; top: 25%;">
   <p style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 5px;">{{{allocatedPerNorm}}}%</p>
   <p>{{{allocated}}}h / {{{norm}}}h</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I work with handlebars, and I am trying to create email templates, and this specific one contains this chart, svg with circles.

If I open the html file in my browser, the template is displayed properly, the chart is clearly shown. But if I send the template via email, with the same parameter values, it acts completely different according to each email box I send it to. For example in Gmail, the chart is not displayed at all, on Yahoo the stroke-dashoffset starts at 9 o clock position, instead of 12 o clock, like I managed to do it in the template, even though the value is still 25.

My main concern is, why am I missing the svg chart in the emails, all I am left with is the div with allocated/norm text and a long list of empty `<u></u>` tags, which, as you can see, is nowhere to be found in my code.

Thank you in advance for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

As for embedding images you'll find no solution that will work in all mail clients. I won't advise using javascript at all in an email. The best solution would be to render the template with one engine before sending it by email. Otherwise you will always have problems.